# Php file upload function works, still echoes error in else clause

Tags: php, file-upload

New in php, i'm trying to experiment file upload mechanism at VERY BASIC level (not trying to test file size etc.)
I wrote a file upload function, testing it with if-else. 
Function works (uploads file successfully)' but still echoes the error string in else clause. Sure i'm missing something but cannot find out what. Code is like this:

```
<?php

function fileupload() {
    $path = "img/";`enter code here`
    $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UNTITLED</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="upload">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(fileupload()) {echo "upload ok";} else {echo "error";}
} else { echo "no submit"; }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fileupload()` is a null return function, so of course your `if` statement always returns false. I think you want something like `return move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name);` to check if it suceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileupload()` function doesn't return any Boolean you have to check if `move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name);` succeeded not the function it self...

```
function fileupload() {
    $path = "img/";`enter code here`
    $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name)) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `fileupload()` function doesn't return anything, making the `if(fileupload())` condition fail, and thereby going to the `else` block. The [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function returns `true` on success, and `false` otherwise. You can use this on your function to return the success status.

```
<?php 
function fileupload() {
    $path = "img/";`enter code here`
    $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];

    // Return the success status
    return move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the exact error you're getting, you should check my comment on why it's not working `fileupload()` returns `null`. To get a return notifying if the `move_uploaded_file` worked, you should change your function to this:

```
function fileupload() {
    $path = "img/";`enter code here`
    $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    return move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name); //This is a bool type return
}
```

However, that might not be the only place the `fileupload()` fails, or the file upload in general fails. You should debug the whole file upload process first before trying to move a `.tmp` file on the server which may not even be there. You can debug this built-in PHP errors for file uploading by accessing the `$_POST['filename']['error']`, which stores all errors from the file upload.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php